# How does a recursion work with respect to a try catch block?

Tags: c++, exception, recursion, iteration, try-catch

I need clarification on how a try block works with recursion.

Say I have a function called `thisFunction` with this structure:

```
thisfunction()
{
    if (...)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {    

            if()
            {
                try {
                    thisFunction()
                }
                catch(...) {
                    throw exception()
                }

                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this runs, if the program ever goes into the `try`, what happens?

Does `thisFunction()` run once before going to the `catch` if it happens to re-run and fall into the `try` block again?

Will it ever even go to the `catch(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is still a function call like any other, it just happens to be a function calling itself.

Each call to `thisFunction()` has its own `try/catch` block when calling the next iteration.  If *any* iteration of `thisFunction()` throws an exception, the exception will be caught by the nearest matching `catch` block, as expected.

If that happens to be the `catch` of a previous `thisFunction()` iteration, then that iteration's `catch` will throw a new exception that will be handled like any other exception.  For multiple iterations of `thisFunction`, the exceptions will continue being caught and thrown until eventually an exception escapes the initial `thisFunction()` call, and will either be caught or not depending on the code that called `thisFunction()` for the first time to start the recursion.

Comment: So if I wanted this to become an iterative function, using the stack method would not work since the majority of the function is not in the try block so the catch would be pretty much useless. Is there a way to go about this without completely restructuring the code?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Make the entire function iterative. Instead of potentially overflowing the stack.  I am wondering if there is a way to do so with still keeping the try catch (or at least whenever a repeated loop makes an exception error the catch will catch it) or if not what would be the best approach. I know I can use a while loop to make a max number of iterations but I want to avoid recession altogether.

Comment: @randomhereok: without seeing the actual code for the entire function, it is difficult to know whether the recursion can be removed or not. Do you need to remember values per iteration? If not, the recursion is wasting stack space. If the function were using tail recursion, the compiler may optimize away the recursion. Or you can rewrite the code into a simple iterative loop without using recursion at all.

Comment: I only need to remember the parameters. I thought tail recursion doesn't work in a try catch.

Comment: @randomhereok well, considering the code shown in the question bails out of the recursion when any iteration throws an exception, you could simply run a single loop inside a single `try/catch` instead and not use recursion at all. If you need to remember values between iterations, you could just store them in a local list.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you mean by a single loop inside a try/catch. Do you mean putting essentially the entire function inside the try catch? Do you mean putting the recursive call in a loop => Does that make it iterative in terms of compiling? If I just store the parameters on a local list instead of recursively call, wouldn't I still need to break the try block and thus avoid the catch?

Comment: You can put the function code inside of a loop and get rid of the function itself, and then put the entire loop inside of a `try/catch`. It would be really useful if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

> When this runs if the program ever goes into the try, what happens?

The same thing that happens when the `try`/`catch` scope is entered, at any other time.

> Does thisFunction() run once

Since `thisFunction()` is invoked immediately, as a first order of business inside the `try` block, then `thisFunction()` will be invoked when the `try` block is entered. No surprises here.

> Will it ever even go to the catch(...)

If an exception is thrown inside the `try` block, then, of course, the `catch` block will catch it, provided that the thrown exception matches the `catch`.

The recursive call does not change that. If an exception gets thrown in the recursive call to this function, then the exception will or will not be caught in exactly the same way as if the recursive call was not made, and the same exception was thrown anywhere else inside the same `try` block.

Once the execution enters the `try` block, the die is cast. If a matching exception gets thrown, it will be caught by the `catch` block. This remains true until the execution thread naturally leaves the `try` scope. Until then, if a matching exception is thrown it will be caught.

Now, if the recursive call entered the same `try` block, and an exception gets thrown, the exception is going to get caught by the `catch` block from the recursive call. When an exception gets thrown, it gets caught by the nearest matching `catch` block, in the execution thread, and the stack gets unwound to that point.

Answer (score 0):

This one just similar to nested try catch block, every try has it respective catch in its class stack and for respective try it will execute respective catch block if exception occurs.